# cpufreq - Is not possible to change "scaling_available_frequencies"

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded-linux

I am trying to change `scaling_available_frequencies` because I am working on a low power system.

I used to do this

```
$ cat /system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies
600000 1200000
```

but I want to reduce frequency to less than 600000.

So I tried the `echo` command to modify scaling_available_frequencies, but I'm stuck.

Is it possible to change `scaling_available_frequencies`?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General answer: The `scaling_available_frequencies` is a read only property in userspace. It lists all the available frequencies which `cpufreq` kernel driver handles. So if you want to have more available frequencies, you first need to ensure that your hardware is capable of it. If there are other frequencies available and they aren't supported yet, you need to extend your driver or device tree (it depends on your particular hardware).

BTW the `cpuidle` driver might be also helpful if you are reducing the CPU power consumption. But again, this heavily depends on your use-case and hardware as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am trying to do what you answer to me.